# HTML5 audio player plays on mobile browser only after double-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio-player

I am creating a custom HTML5 audio player. The player plays audio when the user clicks a button.

```
$("#buttonPlay").click(function () {
var player = document.getElementById("player");
player.play();
});
```

It works fine on desktop, but requires a double-click on mobile browsers. What could the problem be?

Comment: I assume `audio` is not loaded in `cache`.. Make it `preload(preload Attribute)` and check! Also provide the fiddle demo so that one can reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below:

```
var btnplay = document.getElementById("buttonPlay");
var player = document.getElementById("player");

btnplay.addEventListener('touchstart', function(ev) {
   player.play();
})
```